# Why width tkinter widgets are not the same as the tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make three buttons in a row, but the width of the widgets isnt the same factor as the tkinter window (wanted to have each button 1/3 width of the tkinter windows width(400px).

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window.update()
print(window.winfo_width())
button = Button(window, width=window.winfo_width() // 3)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
button = Button(window, width=window.winfo_width() // 3)
button.grid(row=0, column=1)
button = Button(window, width=window.winfo_width() // 3)
button.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

How can i solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thanks everyone i have figured it out.
If someone else has the same problem, [this](https://blog.tecladocode.com/tkinters-grid-geometry-manager/) site might also help.

Comment: Don't use `width=` use `.grid(..., sticky='ew')` and allow the Columns to grow using `window.grid(0, weight=1)`. Do so for all Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you'ver specified images, the width of a button is specified in the number of characters, not the number of pixels.

There are better ways to make sure each button is 1/3 of the window. Since you're using grid, you can force the columns to be equal in size using the `uniform` option. Just set it to the same string for every column, and give every column a non-zero weight so that they grow equally if there's extra space.

Note: I find it much easier to solve layout problems when all of the layout code for a window is grouped together instead of interleaved with other code, so that's how I've structured this example.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")
window.update()
print(window.winfo_width())

window.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2), uniform="equal", weight=1)

button1 = Button(window)
button2 = Button(window)
button3 = Button(window)

button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
button3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thx, another question whats the difference between grid_columnconfigure and columnconfigure?

Comment: @everest: nothing but the name. One is an alias of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying just a **sticky** option in the button won't work.

Using the **grid_columnconfigure** method from **tkinter** with a **non-zero** weight option will configure the columns, letting the button grow or shrink with the window when horizontally stretched.

```
    from tkinter import *
    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("400x400")
    btn1 = Button(text='button 1')
    btn2 = Button(text='button 2')
    btn3 = Button(text='button 3')

    btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
    btn2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ew')
    btn3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ew')

    window.grid_columnconfigure([0,1,2],weight=1)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: That will only guarantee they are the same width if the buttons are naturally the same width. The weight has nothing really to do with the width. It simply tells grid how to distribute extra space.

Comment: @BryanOakley sure thing.. nice explanation