# Tkinter GUI: Replacing one button in a row with a label WITHOUT changing the size of the row. Even by a millimetre

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, label

I made a game where you have a 10*10 grid of buttons. Ten of those are randomly selected to be "tanks". If you click on a tank, the button is replaced with the label "Hit!". The problem I have is that once that happens, the row of that button is either a tiny amount longer or shorter than the other rows. How do I stop this?

```
button[hit] = Label(text="Hit!", padx=5.5)
```

[image]
[image]

If I set "padx" to 5.4, then it is just a bit shorter than the other rows rather than just a bit longer.

[image]

I've tried numbers in between with several decimal points, but it just doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
button = [""] * 100
row = [""] * 10
tank = [""] * 10
showHit = Label(text="Hit!")
prevHits = []

for i in range(10):
    x = 3
    y = random.randint(0,9)
    tank[i] = "(" + str(x) + "," + str(y) + ")"
print(*tank)

def getPos(pos):
    global tank
    print(pos)
    for i in tank:
        if pos == i:
            print("Hit!")
            a = int(pos[1])
            b = int(pos[3])
            print(a, b)  
            hit = a*10# + b
            for i in range(10):
                button[hit].destroy()
                hit += 1
            hit = a*10
            for i in range(10):
                if hit != (a*10) + b and not hit in prevHits:
                    string = "(" + str(a) + "," + str(i) + ")"
                    button[hit] = Button(root, text=string, command=lambda pos=string: getPos(pos))
                    button[hit].pack(in_=row[a], side=LEFT)
                else:
                    button[hit] = Label(text="Hit!", padx=5.4)
                    button[hit].pack(in_=row[a], side=LEFT)
                    prevHits.append(hit)
                print(hit)
                hit += 1



for r in range(len(row)):
    row[r] = Frame(root)
    row[r].pack()
    print(row[r])


num = len(button)
for i in range(num):
    t = i
    t %= 10
    if t == 0:
        r +=1
    if r == 10:
        r = 0
    string = "(" + str(r) + "," + str(t) + ")"
    button[i] = Button(root, text=string, command=lambda pos=string: getPos(pos))
    r = i // 10
    button[i].pack(in_=row[r], side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

Comment: ***WITHOUT changing the size***:Layout on a `Canvas` or use a `Frame`. per widget with `propagate(0)`

Comment: Why don't use grid layout instead?

Comment: You could simply use grid on the widgets and use `grod_proagate(0)` to prevent resizing of widgets.

Comment: I used a grid layout, and it works now. It also makes my life simpler, as rather than trying to delete and rewrite the entire row, I can now target and replace a single button. Thank you all.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: if they are using grid, they don't (and usually _shouldn't_) turn propagation off. There are options to force all rows and columns to be of a uniform size.

Comment: @BryanOakley It steamed like it would be less code then adding a canvas or frame per widget. I could not think of a better option off the top of my head so I only wrote a comment for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why width tkinter widgets are not the same as the tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330820/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl Not quite, but thanks anyway. As mentioned before, I have already found the solution by using grid() instead of pack(). Also, I managed to achieve the goal without using propagate(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing pack() with grid(), consequently removing all frames, and instead putting 10 buttons into each row. I also managed to improve my code:

```
        for i in range(10):
                if not hit != (a*10) + b and not hit in prevHits:
                    button[hit] = Label(text="Hit!", padx=5.4)
                    button[hit].grid(row=a, column=b, sticky = W)
                    prevHits.append(hit)
                print(hit)
                hit += 1
```

Now I can target a button precisely and change it, rather than having to rewrite an entire row in a specific order.