# Cannot resize the Tkinter buttons when using Sticky

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I'm trying to adjust the buttons, but somehow even after changing the **width**, it won't change the size. This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create application window
    app = Tk()

    # title
    app.title("Music Players")

    # geometry
    app.geometry('500x300')

    # background color
    app.configure(bg='orange')

    equation = StringVar()
    window_1 = Label(app, textvariable=equation)
    window_1.grid(columnspan=3, ipadx=100, ipady=10)
    equation.set('music player')

    window_2 = Entry(app, width=30)
    window_2.grid(columnspan=5, ipadx=100, ipady=10)

    # Create buttons and other accessories
    button1 = Button(app, text='PLAY', fg='yellow', bg='purple',
                     command=lambda: press('PLAY'), height=2, width=1)
    button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

    button2 = Button(app, text='STOP', fg='yellow', bg='purple',
                     command=lambda: press('STOP'), height=2, width=2)
    button2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NSEW")

    button3 = Button(app, text='NEXT', fg='yellow', bg='purple',
                     command=lambda: press('NEXT'), height=2, width=2)
    button3.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="NSEW")

    button4 = Button(app, text='PREVIOUS', fg='yellow', bg='purple',
                     command=lambda: press('PREVIOUS'), height=2, width=2)
    button4.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="NSEW")
```

I'm assuming it is because of **sticky="NSEW"**, because when I remove it, the buttons change the size, but there is big spaces between the buttons and also, very spaced out, even though **columns=0** and **columns=1**. 
[image]

How can I change the size of buttons without getting rid of **sticky**? Or, without sticky, but having the buttons next to each other?

My expected output will be like this:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting the buttons to expand to fill the whole window?

Comment: It doesn't need to be! But I just want them to line up nicely.... Somehow when I remove sticky and trying to adjust, I can never put it close to each other than the 2nd picture..

Comment: Your questions are really unclear. Perhaps you can show a picture of what you want the UI to look like.

Comment: I want to show you... .but I was not able to build it... but I will try to draw..??? Hold on!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why width tkinter widgets are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330820/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl I tried, and it seems like it's working, but once I have more letters in the label box ("music player" to "My Music Player"), it goes back to normal...

Comment: ***more letters in the label box***: Make your `Buttonbar` independent from the other widgets by layout it in a own`Frame`

Comment: @stovfl sorry I don't understand it well, I searched frame but I'm very confused. I'm looking for a solution that won't have to change the current code a lot, would that be possible? (maybe not...) I don't really want to change the whole code, then something is not working and I will have to change it back...

Comment: No offense, but that last image does nothing to help clarify what you want. If anything, it makes the question even more confusing.

Comment: @BryanOakley haha no worries I'm not good at drawing. So how should I show? I didn't code based on some other project or the actual music player, I just thought this UI myself. I'm not sure what part you find it confusing? I don't think I can explain it simpler than this............

Comment: Try setting the value of the two `columnspan` to the maximum number of columns (i.e. 4 in your case), and setting same width, for example `width=10`, for the buttons.

Comment: @sahra  Run and see this [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/IndigoElasticLicense) if that's what you want.

Comment: @acw1668 I just tried your solution, and it worked great and simple just as how I wished. Thank you so much.